# Visual Studio stops breaking on assert()

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This started happening today for a Visual Studio 2013 project but I have seen it now and then over the years in other Visual Studio versions.

Running a debug build and for some unknown reason aborts stop raising the message dialog that allows you to break and debug and instead you simple get a message in the output window and the program terminates.

```
R6010
- abort() has been called
The program '[9408] test_explode.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Over many years as a C++ developer this gremlin pops up now and then and I always forget how I solve it and can't see what the cause was. I'm sure someone can shed more light on what's happening and the correct fix and at a minimum I'll at least add my own notes.

A manual call to `_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_MSGBOX)` somewhere in my program restores the correct behaviour. So it appears the default error mode is being set wrong by some compiler option or Visual Studio setting? I'm just not sure what.

All Debug->Exception settings are enabled.

Comment: Does it work if you run inside the debugger?

Comment: This is when launching a debugging session within the IDE